# How can I make a script containing passwords secure?

Tags: macos, security, password, script, mdm

I have made a simple script :

```
sysadminctl -adminUser AdminUserHere -adminPassword AdminPasswordHere -addUser NewUserNameHere -fullName "Full Name Here" -password NewUserPasswordHere
```

Now the system in which this script is need to run will deploy by an MDM. So I need to encode/encrypt/hash the AdminPassword (it can be in script or as argument).

Comment: Which MDM is in play? Most allow for goor hygiene using keychain or obfuscated input or can avoid this entirely with encryption or having to push the script to the filesystem at all.

Comment: MDM is 'Desktop Central' by ManageEngine.